# How to get one specific field of my data with IBM Cloudant and Postman?

Tags: postman, cloudant

I have a database in IBM Cloudant and I use his API url in postman to get data. I have three data (temperature, humidity, sound level) in a JSON file.

How to get one specific field of my data such as Humidity for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve data from CouchDB/Cloudant, you probably want to create a view and then access it.  Try the docs here http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html - you can create views using the cloudant web interface, and you probably want to write a map function that emits the document ID as the key, and the field you're interested in (humidity) as the value.

Comment: If this solved your problem, mark the answer as accepted so people know they should also try this if they have the same question.